# Pretty faces: one mapping configuration for multi .xhtml page

Tags: jsf, url, prettyfaces

I have one question. How could pretty faces do this:

```
<code>
<url-mapping id="home">
    <pattern value="/viewer" />
    <view-id value="/pages/*" />
</url-mapping>
</code>
```

Well, I wonder if pretty faces could hide paths of all .xhtml in folder using just one configuration as shown as above, instead of to config for each and every file.

Comment: Then what page is supposed to be rendered when user goes to `/viewer` path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This mapping doesn't make any sense. To which view should PrettyFaces forward if the client requests `/viewer`?

However, you can do something similar with [Rewrite](http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/), which is the successor of PrettyFaces. With Rewrite you can do something like:

```
.addRule( Join.path("/viewer/{page}").to("/pages/{page}.xhtml") )
```

This will basically map your URLs like this:

- `/viewer/foo -> /pages/foo.xhtml`
- `/viewer/bar -> /pages/bar.xhtml`
- `/viewer/whatever -> /pages/whatever.xhtml`

If you want to migrate your app to Rewrite, which is really simple, have a look at the [PrettyFaces Migration Guide](http://ocpsoft.org/rewrite/docs/migration/prettyfaces3).